# Wix toolset

Tags: wix

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с контролами типа

```
Edit (Control Id="myEdit1" Type="Edit" Property="REMOTE_PORT" Height="17" Width="150" X="56" Y="58" Sunken="yes">).
```

Нигде не могу найти описание как считать то, что ввел пользователь в это поле (например, порт) и как потом это значение использовать при установке вместо значения по умолчанию, которое прописано в конфиге.

**Обновление**

В общем: мне нужно создать установщик для программы, который на определенном шаге будет выдавать диалоговое окно с тремя текстовыми полями (адрес, порт ...). Если необходимо, то пользователь вместо значений по умолчанию должен иметь возможность поменять значения этих параметров.

Соответственно установка программы должна произойти с учетом введенных значений этих параметров(пока что эти значения жестко прописаны в конфиге).

Вот именно последнее я не знаю как реализовать. Помогите литературой, ссылками, а лучше конкретным примером.

Answer (score 1):

[[@Tatyana Druzenko](/users/20517/tatyana-druzenko)](/users/20517/tatyana-druzenko), введенное пользователем значение будет сохранено в свойстве под заданным Вами именем. В данном случае `REMOTE_PORT`. Получить его можно запросив значение свойства по имени. Я так понимаю Вы Custom Action позже выполняете? На хабре есть несколько статей по созданию установочных пакетов, [раз](http://habrahabr.ru/post/71917/), [два](http://habrahabr.ru/post/68616/), [три](http://habrahabr.ru/post/69129/), [четыре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/70616/).

---

**UPDATE**

Раздел Binary нужен для подключения библиотеки с Custom Actions.

**Попробовал сделать небольшой пример**

Допустим у нас есть Custom Action `SelectApplication`. Ему нужно передать три переменные:

- `TARGETDIR`
- `REMOTE_ADDRESS`
- `REMOTE_PORT`

Для этого создаем еще один Action `PrepareSelectApplication`, который эти переменные будет передавать. Чтобы он знал куда, указываем ему в качестве `Property` Id нашего Custom Action (`SelectApplication`).

```
<Binary Id="CustomActionCADll" SourceFile="\CustomAction1\bin\Debug\CustomAction1.CA.dll" />

<CustomAction Id="PrepareSelectApplication" Return="check" Property="SelectApplication" Value="TARGETDIR=[INSTALLLOCATION];REMOTE_ADDRESS=[REMOTE_ADDRESS];REMOTE_PORT=[REMOTE_PORT];" />
<CustomAction Id="SelectApplication" BinaryKey="CustomActionCADll" DllEntry="CustomAction1" />
```

Затем нужно указать порядок выполнения action, делаем это в `InstallExecuteSequence`. Сначала готовим переменные, а затем вызываем сам Custom Action:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="PrepareSelectApplication" After="InstallFiles">NOT Installed</Custom>
  <Custom Action="SelectApplication" After="PrepareSelectApplication">NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Сам Custom Action (на C#, если у Вас C++, смотрите документацию о том как получить переменные там):

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult CanInstall(Session session)
{
    Переменные: 
    // session.CustomActionData["TARGETDIR"]);
    // session.CustomActionData["REMOTE_PORT"]);
    // session.CustomActionData["REMOTE_ADDRESS"]);

    return ActionResult.Success;
}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ. эти статьи я просмотрела много раз и не нашла ни одного подходящего мне примера про контрол Edit.
В каком месте программы я могу получить значение свойства REMOTE_PORT? И как мне все-таки ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ это значение ДЛЯ УСТАНОВКИ программы?
раздел Custom Action должен идти после описания свойств? Нужен ли раздел Binary?

Comment: у меня пока этот кусок кода выглядит так

<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLLOCATION" ></Property>
      <Property Id="REMOTE_PORT" Value="21856"></Property>
      <Property Id="REMOTE_ADDRESS" Value="logs2.papertrailapp.com"></Property>
      <Property Id="FACILITY" Value="Local6"></Property>
      
      <Binary Id="CustomActionCADll" SourceFile="\CustomAction1\bin\Debug\CustomAction1.CA.dll" />
      <CustomAction Id="SelectApplication" BinaryKey="CustomActionCADll" DllEntry="CustomAction1" />

Comment: обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое за пример, Павел. Стало понятнее